# Different onClickListeners for dynamic buttons using RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, button, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am using RecyclerView (and GridLayout) to place dynamic buttons in a grid. **What is the best way to set up a DIFFERENT onClickListener for each dynamic button as it is created using RecyclerView and placed in the Gridlayout?**

My buttons are created randomly depending on a user action by passing a drawable to my RecyclerView in the method "createButton" below. Only one drawable gets passed to my gridLayout at a time, and each time a new onClickListener must be created. What is the best way to go about this?

```
private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<ItemObject> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),myList);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3,
            GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
    return view;
}

public void createButton (Drawable d, String appName){
    rcAdapter.addItem(new ItemObject(appName, d));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a new click listener every time you just need a click listener that is aware of the `ItemObject`. For that, I'll give you my usual approach for such a pattern:

Somewhere in your code you have an `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, you should make that view holder implement `OnClickListener` and give pass the reference of `ItemObject` to the holder during `OnBind`, like following:

```
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ItemObject itemObject;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.findViewById(your button Id).setOnClickListener(this); // make this holder receives the clicks
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // here you add logic that depending on the data from itemObject
    }

}
```

and then during onBind you must properly set the `ItemObject`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (MyHolder holder, int position) {

    ItemObject itemObject = list.get(position);
    holder.itemObject = itemObject;

    // the rest of your bind code....

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew of that approach but didn't know that it would be able to set a different onClickListener for each different button. I was wondering if you also know how to pass "context" to "MyHolder" (in the code you gave). because my onClickListener is opening another activity and so I need to use "getApplicationContext". Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Natalie every view have a method 'getContext()' you receive the clicked view during 'onClick'.

Comment: Yes, I see. I realized I can use "view.getContext" to use context in onClick. Thanks!